# How and when do CAs in Catalyst get feedback on their reviews?

Tags: catalyst, rewards, community

Proposers and vCAs had time to flag/review CA reviews. Where nd when do Community Advisors learn about which of their reviews got flagged (critically, but also marked for constructive feedback) and what is the outcome of this process?

Comment: Timing dependent questions should not be asked here.  Better to post regarding things that have time and circumstance dependent answers on Reddit.

Comment: @gRebel thank you for your suggestion. I didn't know that besides the older Cardano Forums, Telegram groups, Discord, (maybe slack) there's also reddit to monitor.

Answer (score 1):

The vCA's have a google doc (bear with us for now) that we share amongst ourselves for tracking review the reviewers. The CAs remain anonymous while the vCA's do not.

There has been some talk about in the future having a way for CAs to anonymously receive feedback for their reviews that were flagged in order to help guide CAs in the right direction.

I think this would be tremendously valuable, especially as the number of CA's grows almost exponentially in order to keep up with the expanding amount of proposals.

I second that you should simply join the Telegram channel and stay up to date on the latest developments from Project Catalyst, as things are changing very rapidly as we learn what works and discarding what doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the catalyst team is busy collecting and cleaning up all the feedback from vCAs. They will announce the outage as soon as they are able to.

Monitor [the usual channels](https://t.me/ProjectCatalystChat) for announcements!

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking forward to the announcement. It is because I have had no success with the usual channels that I posted this question here. I also thought this may be a good general question to ask, because the documentation outlining the process did not include how and when CAs get notified.